# Asterisk 13 - Substituto para a função AgentCallbackLogin

Tags: linux, centos, sip, asterisk

Existe alguma função padrão para substituir a `AgentCallbackLogin` (descontinuada no Asterisk 1.4 e removida no Asterisk 1.6)?

Usando a função AgentCallbackLogin o agent pode desligar a chamada e o mesmo permanece logado, o mesmo não ocorre com a função AgentLogin, assim que dá o "Hangup" é automaticamente feito o logout do agent.

Alguma solução para este caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aplicação **AddQueueMember** pode ser utilizada como substituição ao **AgentCallbackLogin**, entretando o AddQueueMember não possui um arquivo de configuração como seu predecessor e seu plano de discagem deverá ser alterado de acordo com a nova aplicação, principalmente caso seus agentes participem de várias filas simultâneamente.

Recomendo a leitura [deste](https://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/migrating-from-agentcallbacklogin-to-standard-dialplan-methods-part-1/) excelente post do blog do Leif Madsen, um dos criadores do asterisk, sobre este tipo de migração.